# Поиск четвертого двузначного четного числа

Tags: javascript

Как в найти четвёртое двузначное чётное число, которое при умножении на 16 больше 300?

```js
for (let i = 10; i <= 99; i += 4){
     if (i % 2 == 0 && 16 * i > 300){
         document.write(i)
         break;
      }
 }
```

Comment: логично, что 20 будет первое четное а четвертое будет 26, очень все просто находим первое и добавляем еще 3 четных. Получается не нужен такой длинный цикл и условие не надо и чего i +4 а не +2, и зачем еще считать надо только первое четное! Зачем проверка деления нацело на 2 если и так добавляем по 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var count = 0;
var i;
for (i = 10; i <= 99; i += 2) {
  if (16 * i > 300) {
    if (++count == 4)
      break;
  }
}
console.log(count, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Первое число, которое при умножении на 16 дает число больше, чем 300
let start = Math.ceil(301 / 16);
if (start < 10) // Если оно однозначное
  start = 10;  // то тогда первое двузначное будет 10
else if (start % 2)  // если оно не однозначное, но нечетное
  start++;  // значит нам нужно следующее число
// Теперь нужно просто найти четвертое четное число, считая от текущего
const end = start  + (4 - 1) * 2;
console.log(end);
```